# How to install libboost_python-py36

Tags: python, python-3.x, boost, boost-python

Is libboost_python-py{version} a library in libboost-python-dev?

I have the following on my machine. I use python3.6 on ubuntu 14.04. Do we need to install other things to get libboost_python-py36?

```
# aptitude search boost | grep Python
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package gdb-minimal
W: You may want to update the package lists to correct these missing files
i   libboost-python-dev             - Boost.Python Library development files (de
i A libboost-python1.54-dev         - Boost.Python Library development files
i A libboost-python1.54.0           - Boost.Python Library
p   libboost-python1.55-dev         - Boost.Python Library development files
p   libboost-python1.55.0           - Boost.Python Library
```